# Orchard join between two types

Tags: join, orchardcms-1.6

i have three content types an applicationRecord, an ApplicationDetailRecord and a CustomerPartRecord,  my applicationRecord looks like:

```
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerPartRecord customer { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ApplicationDetailRecord> Details { get; protected set; }
```

now in my applicationService i have a getApplications() function like so:

```
    public IQueryable<ApplicationRecord> GetApplications()
            {
                return _applicationRepository.Table;
            }
```

when this runs it is returning all ApplicationDetailRecords but not the CustomerRecord.  I also have two foreign key defined in my migration file which are

```
        SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey("Application_Customer", "ApplicationRecord", new[] { "CustomerId" }, "CustomerPartRecord", new[] { "Id" });
        SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey("ApplicationDetail_Application", "ApplicationDetailRecord", new[] { "ApplicationRecord_Id" }, "ApplicationRecord", new[] { "Id" });
```

i cant see any reason why the customer record isnt being returned, am i missing anything? how would i get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer, my customerId in ApplicationRecord needed to be Customer_Id, after this it all worked fine!